# Nested map in AWS step function with task inside second map having both map values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am trying to replicate nested for loop in AWS step function using nested maps.

Example

```
xArr : ["A", "B", "C]
YArr : ["1", "2", "3]
```

In normal Java program i would do as below.

```
for (String x : xArr) {
 for (String y : yArr) {
  // do some computation with both x and y variable
 }
}
```

I am trying to achieve the same using step function with below input.

```
{
  "xArr": [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C"
  ],
  "yArr": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
  ]
}
```

Step function definition diagram

[image: Step function definition diagram]

Is this possible in step function?

I tried but i am not able to pass both X and Y variable to the task inside the second map.

Answer (score 0):

Had a more complex task with varying inner loop count (items01/items02). Should also work with static inner loop (items03 instead of items02)

```
{
    "items01": [
        {
            "item01_name": "item01a",
            "items02": [
                {
                    "item02_name": "item02a",
                },{
                    "item02_name": "item02b",
                },{
                    "item02_name": "item02c",
                }
            ]
        },{
            "item01_name": "item01b",
            "items02": [
                {
                    "item02_name": "item02a",
                },{
                    "item02_name": "item02b",
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "items03": [
        "item03a", "item03b"
    ]
}
```

Added the lines to get items03 and item03. Replace any other item(s)02 with item(s)03:

```
{
  "StartAt": "map-items01",
  "States": {
    "map-items01":{
      "Type": "Map",
      "ItemsPath": "$.items01",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "item01.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value.item01_name",
        "items02.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value.items02",
        "items03.$": "$.items03"
      },
      "Iterator": {
        "StartAt": "map-items02",
        "States": {
          "map-items02":{
            "Type": "Map",
            "ItemsPath": "$.items02",
            "End": true
            "Parameters": {
              "item01.$": "$.item01",
              "item02.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value.item02_name",  
              "item03.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
            },
            "Iterator": {
              "StartAt": "run-task01",
              "States": {
                "run-task01": {
                  "Type": "Pass",
                  "End": true
                  "Parameters": {
                    "item01.$": "$.item01",
                    "item02.$": "$.item02",  
                  },
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```